# Class won't toggle on scroll

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone assist me with this? Whenever I try to scroll, the class none doesn't toggle..

```js
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var header = document.getElementsById("here");
    header.classList.toggle("none", window.scrollY > 0);
});
```

```css
.none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" id="here>
```

Comment: Shouldn't img tag needs a class property to toggle?

Comment: `id="here> should be: id="here">`
 there is no such thing as `getElementsById ` id` is unique and it should be:

`getElementById` , voting to close because cosed by typo.

Comment: Voted to close because it's just 2 typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simple didn't close id of img and write `elementsbyid` instead of `elementbyid`.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var header = document.getElementById("here");
    header.classList.toggle("none", window.scrollY > 0);
});
```

```css
.none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" id="here">
```